# Combining two queues producing strange results

Tags: c#, queue

I created a custom Queue class (that I found on here) and another class `Weave` that "weaves" two Queues together into one. This "weaved" Queue is always of type string, and I'm just calling a .ToString() on the values I'm removing from the two source queues as I add them into the weaved queue.

For some reason, when I remove an item from the first queue, the second queue loses all its values except one. The code and example is below:

My queue class:

```
public class Queue<T>
{
    private readonly static Node<T> HeadNode = new Node<T>(default(T));

    private readonly Node<T> _head;
    private Node<T> _tail;

    public Queue()
    {
        _head = HeadNode;
        _tail = _head;
    }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        _tail = _tail.Add(value);
        Count++;
    }

    public T Remove()
    {
        Count--;
        return _head.Remove();
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return GetValues().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(" ", GetValues().Select(v => v.ToString()));
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetValues()
    {
        var current = _head.Next;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Value;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    #region Node

    private class Node<TNode>
    {
        public Node(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
        public T Value { get; }
        public Node<T> Next { get; private set; }

        public Node<T> Add(T value)
        {
            Next = new Node<T>(value);
            return Next;
        }

        public T Remove()
        {
            if (Next == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            var ret = Next.Value;
            Next = Next.Next;
            return ret;
        }
    }
    #endregion 
}
```

Here's the class that "weaves" them into one:

```
public static class Weave
{
    public static Queue<string> DoWeave<T1, T2>(Queue<T1> sourceOne, Queue<T2> sourceTwo)
    {
        Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>();

        while (sourceOne.Peek() != null || sourceTwo.Peek() != null)
        {
            if (sourceOne.Peek() != null)
            {
                q.Add(sourceOne.Remove().ToString());
            }

            if (sourceTwo.Peek() != null)
            {
                q.Add(sourceTwo.Remove().ToString());
            }
        }

        return q;
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it like so:

```
Weave.Queue<int> weaveQueue1 = new Weave.Queue<int>();
Weave.Queue<string> weaveQueue2 = new Weave.Queue<string>();
weaveQueue1.Add(1);
weaveQueue1.Add(2);
weaveQueue1.Add(3);
weaveQueue1.Add(4);

weaveQueue2.Add("one");
weaveQueue2.Add("two");
weaveQueue2.Add("three");
weaveQueue2.Add("four");

Weave.DoWeave(weaveQueue1, weaveQueue2);
```

So in the `DoWeave` function, before the first if statement, my two queues look like this (from the watch window):

```
sourceOne {1 2 3 4} of type Queue<int>
sourceTwo {one two three four} of type Queue<string>
```

Immediately after the single line in the first if statement, `q.Add(sourceOne.Remove().ToString());`,
`sourceTwo` looks like this: `{1}`.

Why would removing an element from the first queue remove a bunch from the second?

Comment: You need to remove `static` from `private readonly static Node<T> HeadNode = new Node<T>(default(T));`. It should be `private readonly Node<T> HeadNode = new Node<T>(default(T));`

Comment: Thank you! I was staring at the code for so long I don't know how I missed that.